# Joining 2 structs from mongodb

Tags: go

I have a function that retrieve the mongodb admin users using `.command`

In the below function, I have the `DbUsers` struct, and I am running the command to retrieve the users from 2 different database.

**My question is,** how can I concat the 2 results (adminUsers & externalUsers) and return after merged? They are of the same `struct`.

```
type DbUsers struct {
    ...lots of stuff about the server
    Users []Users 
}

type Users struct {
   User string
   ...lots of stuff
}

func getUsers() Users {
    admin := CNX.Database("admin")
    external := CNX.Database("$external")

    command := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "usersInfo", Value: 1}}

    var adminUsers DbUsers
    var externalUsers DbUsers
    err := admin.RunCommand(context.TODO(), command).Decode(&adminUsers)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err2 := external.RunCommand(context.TODO(), command).Decode(&externalUsers)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    //New to Golang, not sure what I am doing but this doesn't work


    return []Users{adminUsers.Users, externalUsers.Users}
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to return 2 structs, the result type must be a slice, e.g. `[]DbUsers` and not a single `DbUsers`. Or since this is Go, you may have multiple return types and values, e.g.  `func getUsers() (u1, u2 DbUsers) {}`, and return them like `return adminUsers, externalUsers`.

Comment: If you go with a slice, simply return them like `return []DbUsers{adminUsers, externalUsers}`

Comment: I tried using `[]DbUsers{adminUsers, externalUsers}` but it says **cannot use ([]DbUsers literal) (value of type []DbUsers) as DbUsers value in return statement**

Comment: Allow me to update my question, I think I'm missing some stuff.

Comment: To return a slice, the function signature must specify a slice as the return type: `func getUsers() []DbUsers {}`

Comment: Please take the [Go Tour](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1) if you're not familiar with language basics.

Comment: I've updated my question, and I'm aware of `[]DbUsers {}` in function call. I've fixed that. What I'm missing out in the question is actually i needed to merge `adminUsers.Users` and `externalUsers.Users` which are nested structs. I've also updated the function to return `[]Users` instead of `[]DbUsers`

Comment: After I've split my struct, it appears `append()` now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
return append(adminUsers.Users, externalUsers.Users...)
```